# order one custom post type by modified time of another post type

Tags: query

i have post type name series and another name episodes 
in the homepage i show the series but rank them based on the one that has an episode added to it by time

this is the original code which is only showing by updated for series

```
    <?php 
        $wpquery = new WP_Query(array(
                "post_type"  => "series",
                "showposts"     => $lm,
                "ignore_sticky_posts" => 1,
                "no_found_rows"  => true,
                "update_post_term_cache" => false,
                "update_post_meta_cache" => false,
                "cache_results" => false,
                "orderby" => "modified"
            )); while($wpquery->have_posts()) : $wpquery->the_post();
            get_template_part('series');
        endwhile; ?>
```

i tried this

```
    <?php 
        $wpquery = new WP_Query(array(
                "post_type"  => "series",
                "showposts"     => $lm,
                "ignore_sticky_posts" => 1,
                "no_found_rows"  => true,
                "update_post_term_cache" => false,
                "update_post_meta_cache" => false,
                "cache_results" => false,
                'orderby' => array(
                        "post_type" => 'epsiode',   // taxonomy name
                        "orderby" => "modified",
                )
            )); while($wpquery->have_posts()) : $wpquery->the_post();
            get_template_part('series');
        endwhile; ?>
```

but did not work please help

Comment: `WP_Query` can't do this on its own. How are Series and Episodes linked?

Comment: what do you suggest then there is a custom field in episode with the id of the series

Comment: i think i managed to fix this by using wp_update_post to update series so it would show first again :) i will test it more